# How to enable read only cassandra replication?

Tags: cassandra, database-replication

Is it possible to do Cassandra data replication into another server instance to run read only data operations on it? As we have explored SAN and it become more hardware expensive

Note: 
1. I am not allowed to copy data into file and therefore insert into another instance and tt should be like mirroring of data.
2. The replication should be read only
3. Both instances should in sync
4. If apache is not supported, expecting suggestions on opensource/paid tools in the market

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you setup a second Cassandra Datacenter in your cluster and configure the needed keyspaces to have multi-datacenter support.  Use this data center to handle all of your read only operations and create a read only user ([documentation here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_user_r.html)) that applications in the RO datacenter can use to connect.  In this case the only write operations permitted would be the ones from DC 1 to the RO DC to keep them in sync.  This is the same basic idea as workload segregation in Datastax ([documentation here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/production/singleDCperWorkloadType.html))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !! Actually i am trying to understand the different options , since i have different databases like Elastic search and postgresql hence having one solution for all databases will make a robust design.

Comment: Just remember creating a RO user doesn't make the datacenter strictly read only. In fact that user is available in both DC1 & DC2. Its just how the application routes traffic makes it read or read/write. Make sure write traffic is not routed to "RO DC" by certain loadbalancing policy like "DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy"